# Why is the image of a laser point both real and virtual when shone on a plane mirror?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, laser

I shined a laser pointer on a mirror to see how it reflects, quite interestingly, I saw the image of the laser point on the floor inside the mirror and an image on the floor right beneath me OUTSIDE the mirror without any distortions or loss of resolution. So a plane mirror technically should only produce a virtual image  in all cases, but there seems to be a contradiction here as both a real and virtual image are seen at the same time.

Comment: Please check the question linked above, it's answer provides more details in answering your question.

Comment: It would be much clearer what you're asking about if you added an image with some hand-drawn lines. I think you're asking something different from what the current answers answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement that a plane mirror should only create virtual image in all cases is overly restrictive. It is true that if you are considering a point source of light (such as a point on a pencil you hold near the mirror which scatters diffuse light from the room in all direction but in particular towards the mirror) then the image of that original object formed by the mirror will always be virtual.

However, if the light you are considering is not emanating from a single point but rather consists of collimated light rays (like a laser pointer) or consists of converging light rays then upon reflection from the mirror those light rays *can* re converge to form a real image. However, I'll point out that in the case of a laser beam there is no need for the light rays to converge to illuminate an object or create a spot. I'll just consider the light beam to be collimated from here on out.

What are you are observing in your experiment is that the (collimated) laser light reflects off of the mirror and travels towards the floor (still collimated). If you like you can think of this as there being a "virtual image" of the light beam. Next what happens is the light travels to the floor, hits the floor, and then scatters off the floor. The scattered light from the floor then goes to the mirror and reflects off the mirror creating a virtual image of the floor illuminated by the reflected laser beam.

I hope this clears up your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your mirror isn't a plane mirror, you've lambertian reflection at the mirror floor, therefore you can observe the dot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the LASER just reflected on to the floor by the mirror just check it out & LASER dispersion is very low you can only observe it at long distance.